# Recursively iterate over a nested object to change a key value on all occurrences

Tags: javascript, angular, recursion, lodash, iterated-function

There is an input structure with rules nested inside other rules. In the rules array, wherever there is a 'data' property, its value has to be changed to "foo"

Sample input objects:

1. {condition: 'and', rules: [{data: '123'}]}
2. {condition: 'or', rules: [ { data: '123'},  {condition: 'and', rules: [{data:'123'},{ data:'456'}] }]

Am recursively calling a function to iterate over and if the item has data property, changing its value

My function:

```
function iterateRules(input) {
    input.rules.map(function(item) {
      if(_.has(item, "rules")){
        this.iterateRules(item); //bug-needs extra check like accepted answer 
      } else if(_.has(item, “data”)){
         return item.data = “foo”;
      }
    }, this);
   return input;
 }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you examples used regular, straight quotes and didn't have syntax errors like `[value: ‘456”]`

Comment: Also, do you need to change the item in place or return a new item?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I wanted to return this whole changed object. My bug in the code was  , I was not returning and the extra check if it has rules to recursive call helped (like in approved answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a potential bug in the code you mentioned.

1. In the recursive call to `iterateRules` you are passing `input` instead of `item`
2. You also need to check if the `input` has `rules` property

Try this -

```
function iterateRules(input) {
  if(_.has(input, "rules")) {
    input.rules.map(function(item) { 
      if(_.has(item, "rules")){
        this.iterateRules(item);
      } else if (_.has(item, "data")) {
          return item.data = "foo";
      }
    }, this);
    console.log(input);
  }
}
```

Comment: passing input instead of item was a typo here. But the extra condition helped. And was not returning the input to the caller of this function previously.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recursive approach to achieve this:

```js
const input = {condition: "and", rules: [ { data: "123"}, {condition: "and", rules: [{data:"456"}, {condition: "and", rules: [{value: "456"}]} ] } ]}

function test (obj) {
 if(!Object.keys(obj).includes('rules')) return;
 obj.rules.forEach(x => x.data ? x.data = 'foo' : x);
 return test(obj.rules.find(x => !Object.keys(x).includes('data')));
}

test(input)

console.log(input);
```

note: this function changes input obj.